# PHP laravel Undefined variable: userid in controllers

Tags: php, laravel

This is my sql query

```
select * from users us join EmailBox em on us.userid = em.suserid 
where em.status = "Delete" and (em.suserid="$userid" or em.riemailid="$user")
```

I want to check any one field if "suserid" or "riemailid" result only.
So I changed this in laravel querybuilder.

```
$lists = EmailBox::join('users as us', 'EmailBox.suserid', '=', 'us.id')
                ->where('status' , 'Delete')
                ->where(function($query){
                 $query->where('suserid' , '$userid');
                 $query->orwhere('riemailid' , '$user');    
        })->paginate(5);
```

This query is working fine when the value will be directly passed, 
 userid directly passed 1 means

```
$lists = EmailBox::join('users as us', 'EmailBox.suserid', '=', 'us.id')
                    ->where('status' , 'Delete')
                    ->where(function($query){
                    $query->where('suserid' , 1);
                    $query->orwhere('riemailid' , '$user'); 
        })->paginate(5);
```

This is my code in laravel.
what is mistake?

```
    if(Auth::check()){
        //if(Auth::user()->email!="")
        $user=Auth::user()->email;
        $userid=Auth::user()->id;
        $lists = EmailBox::join('users as us', 'EmailBox.suserid', '=', 'us.id')
                            ->where('status' , 'Delete')
                            ->where(function($query){
                                $query->where('suserid' , '$userid');
                                $query->orwhere('riemailid' , '$user'); 
                            })->paginate(5);
        $links = $lists->render();
        return view('front.index', compact('lists', 'links'));
    }
```

I got error $userid variable is undefined.

Comment: it will return value 1 thats not problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
->where(function($query) use($userid, $user){
    $query->where('suserid' , $userid);
    $query->orwhere('riemailid' , $user); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'use' keyword in your query.

Also write orwhere query as below:-

```
EmailBox::join('users as us', 'EmailBox.suserid', '=', 'us.id')
          ->where('status' , 'Delete')
          ->where(function($query) use ($userid, $user){
              $query->where('suserid' , $userid)
                    ->orwhere('riemailid' , $user); 
          })->paginate(5);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure variable not write in '' (single quote)

```
 if(Auth::check()){
        //if(Auth::user()->email!="")
        $user=Auth::user()->email;
        $userid=Auth::user()->id;
        $lists = EmailBox::join('users as us', 'EmailBox.suserid', '=', 'us.id')
                            ->where('status' , 'Delete')
                            ->where(function($query){
                                $query->where('suserid' , $userid);
                                $query->orwhere('riemailid' , $user); 
                            })->paginate(5);
        $links = $lists->render();
        return view('front.index', compact('lists', 'links'));
    }
```